# MVC textbox postback issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a text box users can enter search criteria. I also have a check box to filter out records. I want them to be able to search on the check box and not have to enter anything in the text box. Every time I leave the text box empty and hit Search, it return the focus to the text box and won't hit the controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Ebooks")) {
    <div class="editor-label">
        Enter Author, ISBN, Title or Imprint
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <p>Enter author, isbn, title or imprint. Use commas to seperate criteria.</p>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchFor)
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.deniedBook)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.deniedBook)
        <input type="submit" value="Search"  />         
    </div>                          
}
```

Model:

public class ItemListViewModel {

```
    public ItemListViewModel() {
        this.Page = 1;
        this.StartPosition = 0;
        this.EndPosition = 0;
        this.TotalResults = 0;
        this.TotalPages = 0;
        this.SearchFor = string.Empty;
        this.deniedBook = false;

    }

    public ItemListViewModel(int count, int pageSize, int page, string searchFor) {
        int startPos = (page == 1) ? 1 : ((page - 1) * pageSize) + 1;
        decimal totalPages = (decimal)count / (decimal)pageSize;

        this.StartPosition = startPos;
        this.EndPosition = ((startPos + pageSize) > count) ? count : (startPos - 1) + pageSize;
        this.TotalResults = count;
        this.Page = page;
        this.TotalPages = (int) Math.Ceiling(totalPages);
        this.SearchFor = searchFor;
    }

    public ItemListViewModel(int count, int pageSize, int page, string searchFor, bool deniedBooks)
    {
        int startPos = (page == 1) ? 1 : ((page - 1) * pageSize) + 1;
        decimal totalPages = (decimal)count / (decimal)pageSize;

        this.StartPosition = startPos;
        this.EndPosition = ((startPos + pageSize) > count) ? count : (startPos - 1) + pageSize;
        this.TotalResults = count;
        this.Page = page;
        this.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalPages);
        this.SearchFor = searchFor;
        this.deniedBook = deniedBooks;
    }

    public int StartPosition { get; set; }
    public int EndPosition { get; set; }
    public int TotalResults { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a search string before submitting the form.")]
    public string SearchFor { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Object> Objects { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ObjectImage> ObjectImages { get; set; }
    public bool deniedBook { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(ItemListViewModel model)
        {
            if (model == null) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("model", model, "Arguments must be provided");

```
        // This action will cache the list if needed then pass the model through the querystring to the search Action
        // Using this method to allow for "back button" compatibility and direct links to searches and pages

        model = PrepareResults(model);

        // Make sure we have records to return
        if (model.TotalResults > 0)
        {
            model = LoadResultSet(model);
            return View("Index", model);
        }
        // If we're still here there were no records

        ViewBag.Message = "No eBooks were found that match the search criteria '" + model.SearchFor + "'.";
        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using any validation attributes in your model?

Comment: Probably `model.SearchFor` is required. Review your validation rules at the model.

Comment: Can you post your model and controller code?

Answer (score 0):

> Every time I leave the text box empty and hit Search, it return the
>   focus to the text box and won't hit the controller.

Your `SearchFor` property is required on Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a search string before submitting the form.")]
public string SearchFor { get; set; }
```

so it is not surprising that if you leave it empty validation fails. If you have enabled client side validation (by including the `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate-unobtrusive` scripts) the controller won't even be hit because validation will occur on the client.

If you don't want this property to be required you should remove the `Required` attribute from it.